# Simple web script runs endlessly instead of only once

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, tampermonkey

I am writing a Tampermonkey script to change the name of something on a webpage. However, the script seems to run endlessly. If the script is ran on the corresponding website (https://www.gutenberg.org/files/46/46-h/46-h.htm), it will turn "Scrooge" into "Happy Scrooge" into "Happy Happy Scrooge", etc., instead of just "Scrooge" into "Happy Scrooge".

Eventually, the page runs out of memory and crashes the tab. Even if there is nothing to re-replace, like just "sad" into "happy", it will still crash the tab within the minute. This seems fairly simple to me but I haven't found a solution online. I would appreciate any help!

I am new to web programming so if anyone has any suggestions for cleaning up my code, I would really appreciate it.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Change Name
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  Changes the name of something on a webpage.
// @author       You
// @match        https://www.gutenberg.org/files/46/46-h/46-h.htm
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    function run () {
        var ele = document.querySelectorAll("p");
        var i, str, n;
        var oldName = "Scrooge";
        var newName = "Happy Scrooge";
        for (i = 0; i < ele.length; i++) {
            str = ele[i].innerHTML;
            n = str.indexOf(oldName);
            if (n > -1) {
                str = str.replace(oldName, newName);
                ele[i].innerHTML = str;
            } else {
                setTimeout(run, 500);
            }
        }
    }

    run();
})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make sure `Happy Scrooge` doesn't get replaced with `Happy Happy Scrooge`, I'd use a regular expression instead: match `(?<!Happy )Scrooge` and replace with `Happy Scrooge` so that a section that's changed doesn't get changed again, with `/(?<!Happy )Scrooge/g`.

But the recursive timeout doesn't make sense - just replace everything once:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Change Name
// @match        https://www.gutenberg.org/files/46/46-h/46-h.htm
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

for (const p of document.querySelectorAll("p")) {
  p.innerHTML = p.innerHTML.replace(/(?<!Happy )Scrooge/g, 'Happy Scrooge');
}
```

Though, at that point, since it doesn't look like `Happy Scrooge` exists anywhere in the original HTML, the lookbehind doesn't look to be needed:

```
p.innerHTML = p.innerHTML.replaceAll('Scrooge', 'Happy Scrooge');
```